# is it possible to apply Convolutional neural network for image classification without resizing?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have database of images of different sizes ranging from (2000x1000) to (400x200). I will be classifying these images to different categories. I believe if I resize these images to eg. (128x128). I will loose of lot of information of the image. Please suggest the appropriate way to deal with this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use max pooling for downsampling and getting the most important features.
More information about MaxPooling [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-max-pooling-in-convolutional-neural-networks)